# Build entry points

Tags: python, setup.py

I am having trouble building Python entry points.

What I enter:

```
  $ python setup.py build
```

What I expect:

The entry points listed in `setup.py` to be available below build

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? In particular, it's unclear what you mean by "entry points".

Comment: it's pretty obvious that he talks about the `entry_points` parameter to the `setup()` function within the `setup.py` file…

Answer (score 1):

well, that's not what "build" does. The build action just prepares the package to be included as a library, not exposing the entry points. To expose the entry points, you either need to use the install action or the develop action.

If you do not want to expose your development globally, then you'll have to use either virtualenv or buildout to make it local to your development path.